# Properties of Waveform Clipping

Tags: operational-amplifier, ac, oscilloscope, voltage-clipping

I just completed (and submitted) a recent lab report in an electronics class on op-amp circuits. The only implementations of the op-amps so far are in the inverted and non-inverted form.

While building and simulating the inverted op-amp circuit, we were asked to take a look at the clipping of the waveform in sinusoidal form (pictured below). I understand that clipping occurs as a form of saturation when the input voltage amplitude gets too high, and I understand how the gain on the waveform works. My question is: why does the clipping only take effect on the bottom of the waveform and not both sides? Does this have anything to do with it being an inverting amplifier rather than a non-inverting amplifier? I noticed that when the input was triangular the output had the clipping effect on both sides.

[Link to Op-amp datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf)

[image: Clipped Voltage]

Here is the circuit diagram of the one I simulated (and built):
[image: Op-amp circuit]

Comment: Invertnng and non-inverting can clip equally well. Look into the DC conditions around the amplifier, and compare the output waveform with both supply rails. You may find ways to improve the amplifier.

Comment: You need to show us a schematic of your circuit, and provide a link to the manufacturer's datasheet for the op amp that you used.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I have included a link to the datasheet of the op-amp used. Is it possible that I would find a detail about its clipping properties in the datasheet somewhere?

Comment: This surprises me. Your schematic is correct, except for the output which is tied to ground and of course can't work. However you are using the LM741 and not the uA741 which most textbooks describe. The output stage seems different. IIRC the original 741 *should* clip more or less symmetrically. In any case you shouldn't rely on clipping behaviour unless stated on the datasheet

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the architecture of you op-amp.

Amps designed for bipolar supplies usually clips in the same way on both positive and negative limits.

Single supply amps often can reach really near the ground (which is really useful for DC signals)

Output rail-to-rail can be build in different ways, they are either using an output stage which can go at some mV of the power rail or even contain a charge pump to boost the output; in fact some can even go over the power rail.

Really old amps when overdriven can run in phase inversion (really ugly).

In short do not ever rely on the clipping behaviour and stay inside the declared working area, unless something is explicitly guaranteed in the datasheet (they something do this).

In true differential topologies it even gets funnier…

Strange thing however: the LM741 has usually symmetrical clipping, but it's designed for dual rail supply. How are you powering it? also, if it's a simulation, it seems that some models are better than others, they discuss it there:
https://e2e.ti.com/support/amplifiers/f/14/t/551647?LM741-OpAmp-behaviour

Comment: Thanks! I have also included a link to the op-amp datasheet since you mentioned it would depend on my op-amp's architecture :)

Comment: The 741 is something like the oldest amp ever invented. For today standard it has horrible specs. But at least is cheap :D In fact it has the dreaded phase reversal when going out of common mode

Comment: Since it seems like it would help get a more specific answer, I added a picture of my circuit diagram.